# how to keep on websocket on boost::beast?

Tags: c++, boost, beast

I referenced [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp) documents about boost::beast websocket-async.

I removed "ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal..." on on_read function in order to avoid disconnection.

But beast websocket is disconnected by ending on_read.

```
std::make_shared<session>(ios)->run(host, port, text);
ios.run(); // I want to keep running it until explicit calling close.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the code

```
    // Close the WebSocket connection
    ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,
        std::bind(
            &session::on_close,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1));
```

with the logic you want. What do you want to happen instead? Do you want to read more? Then do another read like above:

```
    // Read a message into our buffer
```

Comment: thanks, I want to avoid to close websocket, then I removed async_close. But websocket is still closed automatically.

Comment: What _else_ did you do instead? Also keep in mind the other end could be disconnecting